# Send outlook calendar invite from Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, outlook, mime-types, actionmailer

I am trying to send a calendar invite from my Rails app. It seems to work fine in Gmail, but not in outlook, where it is sent as an attachment.

I have tried every suggestion out there on the Internet, but just cant get it to work.

```
class Notifications < ActionMailer::Base
  def add_interaction
    @i = i
    ical = Icalendar::Calendar.new
    e = Icalendar::Event.new
    e.start = DateTime.now.utc
    e.start.icalendar_tzid="UTC" # set timezone as "UTC"
    e.end = (DateTime.now + 1.hour).utc
    e.end.icalendar_tzid="UTC"
    e.organizer @i.interviewer_email
    e.created = DateTime.now
    e.uid = e.url = "#{HOSTNAME.to_s+'/interaction/'+@i.id.to_s}"
    e.summary "#{INTERACTION_TYPE[@i.itype][0]} with #{@i.company}"
    e.description <<-EOF
    #{INTERACTION_TYPE[@i.itype][0]} with #{@i.company}
    Date: #{@i.start_time.strftime('%e %b %Y')}
    Time: #{@i.start_time.strftime('%I:%M %p')}
    EOF
    ical.add_event(e)
    ical.custom_property("METHOD", "REQUEST")

    email=mail(to: "sample@email.com", subject: "Interview",mime_version: "1.0", content_type:"text/calendar",body:ical.to_ical,content_disposition:"inline; filename=calendar.ics", filename:'calendar.ics')
    email.header=email.header.to_s+'Content-Class:urn: content-classes:calendarmessage'
    return email
  end
end
```

and it's called as

```
Notifications.add_interaction(Interaction.last).deliver
```

I also tried to construct the mail as

```
    email=mail(to: "nikhil@talentauction.in,nikhil@zobtree.com", subject: "#{@i.bid.company.name} has suggested a time for #{INTERACTION_TYPE[@i.itype][0]}",mime_version: "1.0", content_type:"multipart/alternative",body:'')
    html_body = render_to_string("/notifications/add_interaction")
    email.add_part(
        Mail::Part.new do
            content_type "text/html"
            body html_body
        end
    )
    p = Mail::Part.new do
        content_type 'text/calendar; method=REQUEST name="calendar.ics"'
        content_disposition "inline; filename=calendar.ics"
        content_transfer_encoding "8bit"
        body ical.to_ical
    end
    p.header=p.header.to_s+'Content-Class:urn: content-classes:calendarmessage'
    email.add_part(p)
```

But in all cases calendar invite is delivered as an attachment in the outlook.

**I noticed something strange, which could be the cause of this. When I viewed the source of email, in both cases the topmost mimetype was `multipart/mixed`, (instead of `text/calendar` the first time and `multipart/alternative` the second time)**

Whereas when sending the email from console, it says this

```
Message-ID: <5332b0db144e8_1a80129d7f866915@skynet.mail>
Subject: Talent Auction has suggested a time for Introduction Call
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/calendar;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: inline;
 filename=calendar.ics
filename: calendar.ics
Content-Class: urn: content-classes:calendarmessage

BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:REQUEST
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
PRODID:iCalendar-Ruby
BEGIN:VEVENT
CREATED:20140326T162000
DESCRIPTION:        Introduction Call with Talent Auction\n     Date: 28 Mar 2014\n 
    Time: 04:00 PM\n
DTEND:20140327T105000Z
DTSTAMP:20140326T105000Z
DTSTART:20140326T105000Z
CLASS:PUBLIC
ORGANIZER:nikhil@zobtree.com
SEQUENCE:0
SUMMARY:Introduction Call with Talent Auction
UID:localhost:300019
URL:localhost:300019
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

**EDIT:** I am using mandrill for sending emails, if that would be of any help

Comment: can you post the source of the email with full headers when _not_ sent from the console?

Answer (score 2):

afair outlook happily accepts events if attached in the 'right' way. cant simulate your setup right now, so all i can try to help is bit of guessing.. please try:

```
email = mail(to: "sample@email.com", subject: "Interview", mime_version: "1.0", content_type: "text/plain", body: ical.to_ical, content_disposition: "attachment; filename='calendar.ics'")
return email
```

and if that fails too please try:

```
... content_type: "text/calendar" ...
```

for your other approach that would hopefully be:

```
p = Mail::Part.new do
    content_type "text/plain; name='calendar.ics'"
    content_disposition "attachment; filename='calendar.ics'"
    content_transfer_encoding "7bit"
    body ical.to_ical
end
```

and if that fails too please try

```
... content_type "text/calendar" ...
```

instead.

in addition, please keep in mind that the sender needs to be in the receiver's address book to have events added without confirmation. furthermore, there is an ical validator at http://severinghaus.org/projects/icv/. curious to get your feedback..

Comment: Will try this over the weekend and accept and give bounty if any of this works

Comment: any chance you having a glimpse?

Comment: Hey, sorry. Forgot to reply. Tried this but it didn't work. Hence I upvoted, but didnt accept

Comment: Most(90%) clients are using Google apps, which is rendering it correctly. So finally gave up on this for now after spending too much time. Will probably come back later when I have a little less load

Comment: thanks, if you could specify on the didn't work aspect i'd try to progress

Comment: well, it still goes as an attachment to all outlook email addresses.

Comment: 'd need to see headers and stuff... so let's call it a question here :) regards

Answer (score 2):

The following is working for me, with Rails 6.1, using an `ApplicationMailer` and creating the `.ics` file with the `icalendar` gem v2.8.0:

```
## InviteMailer < ApplicationMailer

def invite
  ... ## creating icalendar calendar and event

  attachments['event.ics'] = {
    mime_type: 'multipart/mixed', ## important because we are sending html and text files for the body in addition to the actual attachment
    content_type: 'text/calendar; method=REQUEST; charset=UTF-8; component=VEVENT',
    content_disposition: 'attachment; filename=event.ics',
    content: ical.to_ical
  }

  mail(
    to: user.email,
    subject:  "Email subject..."
  )
end
```

It works fine both with Gmail and Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

Mandrill can't handle calendar invites so it filters them out when your email is sent.

From a support request:

> Currently we're unable to support the inline message portion that
>   Outlook and some other email clients use to attach calendar invites.
>   Rather than attaching those invites as separate files, those clients
>   include the calendar invite as its own message portion (like the text
>   section or HTML section of the message). When Mandrill's parser hits
>   that inline invite section, it will skip over them since they don't
>   conform to anything that it knows how to abstract away. It's not true
>   text or HTML, attachment or embedded image.
>
> In the future, we'll look into adding special support for this
>   particular form of message as it's quite popular, but I can't provide
>   any specific ETA on when that might be. In the meantime, you might
>   consider generating the .ics files and attaching them, just as you
>   might with other types of attachments through the Mandrill API or SMTP
>   integration.

Answer (score 0):

Following multiple infos in various topics I ended up to make it work :

```
    mail to: "xx@outlook.com",
     subject: 'first event outlook',
     mime_version: '1.0',
     content_type: 'text/calendar; method=REQUEST; charset=UTF-8; component=VEVENT',
     body: cal.to_ical,
     content_disposition: "attachment; filename='calendar.ics'"
```